# parse error alternating color rows

Tags: php, echo

stumped over quotation marks there are a lot of combinations

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'align' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 34

```
$color="1";
{
  if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>

echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";   ///LINE 34
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . "<a href=\"{$row['page']}\"><img src=\"{$row['img']}\">" . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td align='center' width='10'>" . $row['Ages'] . "</td>";

echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Comment: You forgot `";` on this line: `echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>`. The syntax highlighter makes it kind of obvious.

Comment: When an error as such is thrown, it doesn't necessarily come from "that" line. Just a quick "fyi" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing double quote and a semicolon here:

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>
```

should be

```
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this `echo`:

```
  if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>
```

You need to close it like this:

```
  if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#000000'>";
```